# Is it possible to print a poloniex error message?

Tags: python, json, api, error-handling, poloniex

I try to withdraw crypto currencies from my Poloniex wallet to external wallets in python with the Poloniex module, which works pretty good with the following code:

```
from poloniex import Poloniex
from poloniex import PoloniexCommandException

polo = Poloniex("my_api_key", "my_api_secret")

try: 
    r = polo.withdraw(currency = "LTC", amount = "0.5", address = "MH...W5")

except PoloniexCommandException:
    print("doesn't work")

else:
    print("successful")
    print(r["response"])
```

If there is no error during withdrawal process, everything is fine. If there is an error (I don't have enough balance or address is wrong), it will print `doesn't work`, as intended.
If I print `r`, I will get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\phil\Desktop\Python\poloniextest.py", line 12, in <module>
    r = polo.withdraw(currency = "LTC", amount = "0.5", address = "MH...W5")
  File "C:\Users\phils\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\poloniex\poloniex.py", line 300, in withdraw
    return self._private('withdraw', currency=currency, amount=amount,
  File "C:\Users\phil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\poloniex\poloniex.py", line 50, in _fn
    raise PoloniexCommandException(respdata['error'])
poloniex.exceptions.PoloniexCommandException: Not enough LTC.
```

Now I want to print this message from the error: `Not enough LTC.`

Is it possible to print this message?

Answer (score 1):

If you save the Exception in a variable, you can print the error message easily:

```
except PoloniexCommandException as e:
    print(e)
```